# Can I speed up groupby on multicolumns followed by diff with 1 period?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I've got a DataFrame like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0, 3, 10**7), 
                   'b': np.random.randint(0, 4000, 10**7), 
                   'c': np.random.random(10**7)}
```

I want to group by the first two columns (unordered, about the same number of groups as I've provided here), and then diff the third column.

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).c.diff(periods=-1)
```

Sadly this is pretty slow for me, but I guess it is quite a bit of work.

```
>>> %timeit df.groupby(['a', 'b']).c.diff(periods=-1)    
10.2 s ± 75.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Is there any way I can avoid a Pandas groupby to speed this up? I'm aware when doing a groupby->reduce in Pandas it is often possible to replace with pure NumPy, but I am not sure if there is anything clever to do here in place of the groupby operation.

Comment: sometime for loop run faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really an interesting problem since routinely we just go for `groupby()`, even though it is rather expensive.

Here's another approach that would be faster:

1. sort by `['a','b']`
2. compute diff, mask the last row in each block with `NaN`

and the code:

```
s = df.sort_values(['a', 'b'])
df['diff_c'] = (s['c'].diff(periods=-1)
                       .where(s.duplicated(['a','b'], keep='last'))
                )
```

On my computer your code runs in 8.5s while the above runs in 1.8s.